# What tools/methods are used to consume WCF web services for Android?

Tags: c#, android, wcf, web-services, android-studio

I am designing an Android application which is supposed to connect to a server via WCF web service.

I have a WCF web service written in .NET 4.5 and it is a self-hosted web service. It has SOAP endpoint configuration and it is not a very complex service, however it does include some methods which return DTOs (Classes containing lists, other DTOs and value types).

Now the problem I am facing is that I wish to use some sort of tools to consume the web service definition and generate the proxy classes. I have been successful doing this with the help of Eclipse, but the resulting generated code uses alot of external libraries not available within Android.

Now my question is, what are the preferred tools/methods to consume WCF SOAP web services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using the following tool gave me the best generated code.

https://code.google.com/p/android-ws-client/

I do recommend this tool to anyone looking for consuming a WCF SOAP web service.